# Close all Windows File Explorer windows, but don't kill the explorer.exe shell

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, cmd.exe

On the command line on Windows 8.1, how can I kill/close all Windows file explorer windows... but without killing and restarting the shell?

It's crazy that they're the same process.

Comment: You may want to read up on this here to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24911112/close-folders-window-with-batch-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the command line utility [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) (freeware) ([archive.org's mirror for the webpage](https://web.archive.org/web/20180415224443/http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html); [archive.org's mirror for the binary](https://archive.org/details/NirCmd-2.81)) and execute:

```
nircmd.exe win close class "CabinetWClass"
```

I use it on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate  and it works as intended: it will  close all Windows Explorer windows, but won't kill the `explorer.exe` process.

The program is supposed to work on Windows 9x/ME, Windows NT, Windows 2000, Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008, Windows 7, Windows 8, and Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry it took so long to mark "answered". I'd totally forgotten I'd posted this question over a year ago, and just searched for a solution on Google again now only to find my own question here!  nircmd rocks.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing Franck's brilliant response:

You can automate a shortcut to this command by following the steps:

- create a new folder somewhere you like
- inside it, paste the app "nircmd.exe"
- still inside it, create an expkill.txt file with the command informed by Franck:
  `nircmd.exe win close class "CabinetWClass"`
- change the .txt file extension to .bat file, turning into expkill.bat
- create a shortcut to this file and change its name to just "expkill"
- move this shortcut to the 'user folder'

### Result

now whenever you type the steps below, windows explorer windows will be closed WITHOUT terminating the explorer.exe process

- [CTRL + R]
- expkill
- [ENTER]

### Note

Don't know how to access the user's folder?
Follow the instructions:

- type [Win + R]
- type just a dot:.
- type [enter]
- the folder you open is the user's folder